# $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is open in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ but not closed?

Tags: topological-groups

It is well known that for any subgroup $F$ of a topological group $G$. If $F$ is open in $G$, then it must be closed $G$.

However, we know:

1. $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is open in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$
2. $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup

But we also know $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is NOT closed, from the example in [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/535725/549321):

> there exists a sequence $A_n$ in $GL(n,R)$ such that $A_n$ tends to
> $A$ as $n$ to infinity where $A$ is not invertible.For
> instance,considering $n=2$,let $A_n=\begin{pmatrix} 1 && 0\\ 0 &&
> > \frac{1}{n}\end{pmatrix}$.Then $limA_n=A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 && 0\\ 0 &&
> > 0\end{pmatrix} ,n\to{+\infty}$,where $det(A)=0$.The example tells us
> that $GL(n,R)$ is not closed in $M_n(R)$.

Isn't that contradictory?

Comment: $M_n(R)$ is not a group wrt the product of matrices

Comment: @user8268 Thanks! Question solved!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been answered in a comment.